# Who are Sheldon's references of Crunch and Kangaroo?

Tags: character, dialogue, reference, star-trek, the-big-bang-theory

In this clip of *The Big Bang Theory*, before sacrificing himself, Sheldon says

> Following in the footsteps of Kirk, Crunch and Kangaroo.

I know Captain Kirk died and later sacrificed himself in the [Star Trek: Generations](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0111280/?ref_=nv_sr_2) movie.

Who are the other two characters?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

He just means he's appointing himself a **"Captain"** and leading...

Other than that the references have nothing in common.

**Captain Crunch** is a character on (or the name of) a US breakfast cereal.

[image]

**Captain Kangaroo** is an American children's television series that aired weekday mornings on the American television network CBS for nearly 30 years, from October 3, 1955, until December 8, 1984.

There was no actual kangaroo in the [**show**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_Kangaroo)..

> (the name "kangaroo" came from the big pockets in his coat)